# normalize PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

[image]I have a PostgresQL database that I populate programmatically in my Java application code. There is a table "Message" - it stores incoming messages from the mail service. And also "Phone" - which stores phone numbers. The UUID for each entity is automatically generated. The problem is that if the message can contain the same number. And in the database, due to auto-generation, phone_id is always different (see photo). How to avoid this?[image]

Comment: A unique constraint on the phone number?

Comment: this is of course yes, but I need messages (i.e. message _id ) that have the same number to correspond to the same phone_id

Comment: Too late for commenting, but if it does not satisfy the requirement you may check the phone_number each time and attach the new message to duplicate phone_number then .

Comment: What **is** `phone_id` ? what does it *mean* ?

Comment: there are phone numbers inside the message - I assigned them an id to establish a connection

Comment: Why not to use entities associations then? isnt the reason we picked relational database for it ?  @Buba

Comment: i have a one to many association
Message-phone

Comment: One message goes to many phones? Not many messages go to many phones? Why is the number not included inside the table that `phone_id` references?

Comment: one message can have multiple phones and a phone can appear in multiple messages

Comment: So it's a many-to-many relationship (what you're showing is the link table). You just need to remove the phone number from it and include it in the phone table.

Comment: its many to many association then :)

Comment: see photo , please - i edit question @Kayaman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this answer is not about normalization, I hope it helps. In case you want to link a UUID number to a phone number, you can also generate UUID v3 or UUID v5 instead of UUIDv4. A UUIDv4 is random, while the UUID v3/v5 is always the same for the same input.

To generate a UUIDv3:

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.UUID;

public class Example {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string1 = "89207143040";
        String string2 = "8 920 714 30 40";
        String string3 = "+8 920 714-30-40";
        
        // Remove all non numeric chars from the phone number and generate a UUIDs v3.
        UUID uuid1 = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(string1.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "").getBytes());
        UUID uuid2 = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(string2.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "").getBytes());
        UUID uuid3 = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(string3.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "").getBytes());
        
        System.out.println(uuid1 + " -> " + string1);
        System.out.println(uuid2 + " -> " + string2);
        System.out.println(uuid3 + " -> " + string3);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
84345d67-45a8-365e-8da7-5d5c90c1ce0c -> 89207143040
84345d67-45a8-365e-8da7-5d5c90c1ce0c -> 8 920 714 30 40
84345d67-45a8-365e-8da7-5d5c90c1ce0c -> +8 920 714-30-40
```

Answer (score 0):

One practice is to use constraint on the `phone_id` field to avoid the duplicate entity with same `phone_number`.

In the case you are using database-independent library for managing the databases like **Liquibase** you can achieve it by

```
<changeSet  author="liquibase-docs"  id="dropUniqueConstraint-example">  
<dropUniqueConstraint  catalogName="cat"  
        constraintName="const_name"  
        schemaName="your schma name"  
        tableName="Message"  
        uniqueColumns="phone_number"/>
```

Or directly in database with

```
ALTER TABLE Message ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (phone_number);
```

An other approach for satisfying [2NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is to create alternate table which foreign key pointing to phome_number in `Message` table with `One to Many` [association](https://javatpoint.com/jpa-one-to-many-mapping#:%7E:text=The%20One-To-Many%20mapping,of%20instances%20of%20another%20entity.) or `Many to Many` if they have bidirectional relation .